# comparing two tables

Tags: sql-server

I have two identical table ie all the columns are identical and one of the datatype is Text, one is varchar(255) and the rest are int.
Lets say the table name is 'AAAAA'. 
Table AAAAA was processed and backed up earlier this month.
Both the tables were storing data and now the second table is only storing data.
I need to find unmatching records from the second table (BBBBB) which is storing data right now and add those records to Table AAAAA.

Your help will be highly appreciated. I tried to use 'EXCEPT' but it does not support text datatype.

I'm using SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Is one of the columns an ID or is the table just a heap?

Answer (score 3):

Get a copy of [redgate's SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio 2010 Premium or above you can use the [data compare tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833428.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Answer to marks question: The Primary key is the combination of 6 fiels/columns.

Comment: This should be added as a comment, not as an answer.

Comment: I am using IE 6, Sometime the Add comment button does not show up.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do a left join using your primary key fields the rows with null values for your 'AAAAAA' table will be null.

Comment: That would get new rows in BBBBB that do not exist in AAAAA. You'd still need to handle rows that have been deleted from BBBBB and rows that exist in both tables but have had some column(s) updated in BBBBB.

Comment: The question to me sounds like he is trying to find records that exist in AAAA and add them to BBBB nothing more. "I need to find unmatching records from the second table (BBBBB) which is storing data right now and add those records to Table AAAAA."